# Convert pdf text with only superscript and subscript formatting elements to LaTeX

Tags: pdf

I have a long text in pdf with lot of sub and super scripts and need to have it in LaTex. 
Sorry I could not find something working in previous answers on converting pdf to latex. (OS Windows 7)

Now I found that both abiword and Writer2LaTeX works good with sub and superscripts. The confusion for me was how to use them starting from pdf. Sorry for everybody who spent time for my question and THANKs.

Comment: I had tried  AbiWord, which has export to Latex. But how to import .pdf? (v.2.8.6. for windows).

Comment: if you don't want a word processor you can use  pdftotext or similar utilities. Whatever you use, the superscripts may be lost or may come out as normal text or may come out as the unicode superscript characters, depending on how the pdf is constructed.

Comment: Thank you David for your comments. I tried such way and it works: 1)
First let us convert from .pdf to .docx. I have done this by Adobe Acrobat Pro, tools-export file to – Microsoft Word Document. 2)
Download Writer2LaTeX from http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/writer2latex
Install Latex export in OpenOffice 4.1.1, Tools – Extensions manager – Add - and choose file with   writer2latex

Comment: 3) Open .docx by OpenOffice. We see that sub-super-scripts are in place but some other formatting has been lost during pdf-docx conversion. 
4) File – Export – LaTex2e
Format – default, Result – built-in, encoding – UTF-8, support additional symbols.      
We see that sub-super scripts are ok being served by \textsubscript  and \textsuperscript